# Increment ID in text file - Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to open a file, read the ID (integer) in the file, increment the ID then write the newly obtained ID in the file.
I am struggling as I am having outputs that I don't really understand. I tried several things but I don't understand 1- what is the problem 2- what should I do to solve the problem.
Thanks for any help !
[console returns the following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9lPR.png)

Here is the code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { isNumber } = require("util");

var index_feb;
fs.readFile('Shared/feb_index.txt', function (err, data) {
  //parseInt(data).toString()
  //index_feb = data;
  console.log(data);
  data.toString("utf-8");
  console.log(data);
  const i = parseInt(data.toString("hex"), 16)
  isNumber(i);
  var l = i;
  console.log(l); 
  l ++;
  index_feb = String(l);
  console.log(index_feb);
  console.log(l); 
});


fs.writeFile(path = 'Shared/feb_index.txt', data=String(index_feb), function (err, data) {} );
```

Comment: `fs.readFile` is asynchronous, to write after reading it, you need to move the writeFile command inside the callback function where you increment the value. Also note that functions calls on their own often do nothing; `.toString()` for instance returns the new value, but you're discarding that. Similarly for `isNumber`, you need `if (isNumber(i)) ...`

Comment: You should change `data.toString("utf-8");` to `data = data.toString("utf-8");` or else it converts the `Buffer` to a string, but does not assign it to `data`. And is the integer in base 10 ?

Comment: @astroide the integer is not base 10, I removed it thank your for your remark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @asteroide and @Chris G, by mixing the elements I obtained the wanted result.
Here is the final code:

```
const fs = require('fs');

var index_feb;
fs.readFile('Shared/feb_index.txt', function (err, data) {
  //parseInt(data).toString()
  //index_feb = data;
  data = data.toString("utf-8");
  console.log(data);
  const i = parseInt(data);
  var l = i;
  console.log(l); 
  l ++;
  index_feb = String(l);
  //console.log(index_feb);
  console.log(l); 
  fs.writeFile(path = 'Shared/feb_index.txt', index_feb, function (err, data) {} );
});
```